# Any way to have git add a file from master into 10 other branches?

Tags: git

Is there any way to tell git to add a new file into every other branch?

Rather than `git checkout <branch>; git merge master` for every branch, is there a shortcut for adding *newfile* into each branch below?

```
     master
       +-----newfile
       |
      --- 
    /  |  \
   /   |   \
  /    |    \
foo   bar   baz
```

EDIT: This is the bash script (needs some cleanup if implemented) I came up with but hoping there's a better way.

```
MSG='added newfile which contains a method to workaround issue IS-797'
for branch in $(git branch | grep -v master | sed 's#^[ *\t]##g'); do
   echo merging into $branch
   git checkout $branch && git merge master -m "$MSG"
done
```

Comment: Write a bash script that does what you need in a loop )

Comment: added! I was hoping there would be a better way

Comment: Use `git cherry-pick`

Comment: Perhaps I am misinterpreting your diagram, but if master is an ancestor of foo, bar, and baz, and the merge-base of all three is a descendant of the commit that added the new file, then the new file is already in all 3 branches.

Comment: OTOH, if time in your diagram is moving up, and foo, bar, and baz were merged to form master, then it looks like foo, bar, and baz are no longer being developed, so why do you care if the file is in them?

Comment: @WilliamPursell for my purpose, `master` is a set of base files I place on many systems. `foo` contains files from master, plus additional ones only specific to the system needing the `foo` branch.  Sometimes I need to make a change on one of the base files. I do this change in `master` and merge it down to the other branches. Sometimes I need to change one of the specific files to the `foo` branch which never gets merged to `master`.  Hope that clears it up. I'm probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about this.  Most of the advice in other comments/answers (as of this writing) are suspect in my opinion.  Here's a rundown of different options, with pros and cons.

First of all, there are (at least) three different options for what the final history can look like.  Each has pros and cons.  Sort of.  More like each has cons, and the pros are that it doesn't have the other ways' cons.

- It can look like the file was "always there", since before the affected branches were created.  The big down-side is that this is a history rewrite, and that has consequences.
- It can look like the file was independently added by each branch.  The file will likely end up with a hard-to-read history, and there's a lot of potential for avoidable merge conflicts.  But, it doesn't rewrite history.
- It can look like the file was added once, and then merged into each branch.  Some people really hate merge commits, and even as someone who *doesn't* particularly hate merge commits I think this approach leads to a messy branch topology.  But, it avoids the history rewrite and will work well going forward; i.e. it's functionally the cleanest option, but aesthetically rough.

Looking at each in more detail:

---

*Rewriting History* :

If you alone use your repo, and you've never done anything that makes your existing commit ID's ("hashes") important, then this is a fairly attractive option.  Even if you share the repo, you can make this work as long as you coordinate with the other users of the repo.

For big rewrites, my general advice is to coordinate with everyone to have a set date/time when all work will be pushed to the repo.  Then everyone discards their clones, you do the rewrite, and everyone re-clones.  If that's not practical, then a big rewrite probably isn't a good idea; but if you want to consider it anyway, read up on "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` docs for more information about what will have to happen.

While `rebase` is, I suppose, the prototypical way to do a history rewrite, in this case it's almost certainly the wrong way.  If you have many branches, you have to do it many times.  If you have a complex history, it becomes very hard to do correctly.  In particular it doesn't deal with merges well (even with recently-added improvements).

Instead you could use `git filter-branch`.  The easy way is with a `--tree-filter`.  You would put a copy of the file somewhere outside the work tree, then

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp /path/to/stored/copy/of/file path/to/file/in/worktree' -- --all
```

Then `filter-branch` will proceed to check out each commit in your history, run the `cp` command to add the file to the worktree for that commit, and write a new commit with the resulting content.  Then it will move branches from the old commits to the new ones.  If you have tags and want them to move, too, add a `--tag-name-filter` argument like

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp /path/to/stored/copy/of/file path/to/file/in/worktree' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

The problem with this is, if your history is large, the process is slow.  You can speed it up by using a ramdisk for the work tree (see the `-d` option), or by using an `--index-filter` instead of a `--tree-filter` (but this requires you to use different commands to directly update the index, and it's not quite as simple).

---

*Each Branch Adds the File*

This is what `cherry-pick` would get you.  Since the question is about how to *automate* the process, it's unclear why someone commented with `cherry-pick` as though it were a solution.  The process is just as manual (and just as scriptable) as merging.

The only difference is, when you do it this way git creates independent commits that individually add the file on each branch.

You could use the same basic script for this as you use for merging, just replacing the `merge` command with the `cherry-pick` command.

---

*Merges*

For this, you already have drawn up a reasonable solution - you need a script.  The only think I would note is, `git for-each-ref` is often a more suitable command for feeding into a script, rather than `git branch`.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rebase` to achieve it, but do read why you should not use git rebase from [this article](https://medium.com/@fredrikmorken/why-you-should-stop-using-git-rebase-5552bee4fed1)

Comment: Ugh.. rebasing sounds like a new way to kill yourself with merge conflicts. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ServerFault Use git rebase only when you don't have any other option. Or maybe if its your hobby project and you can afford to mess things up

Comment: @argo I disagree both with your premise that you should never use rebase and the article you linked that seems to imply that "Since some people do rebase bad- no one should use rebase!!". Its a powerful command that I've found very useful in industry

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the commit on `master`, I would simply cherry-pick it on each branch. This seems by far the simplest and most robust one to script; a failure in one branch should be inconsequential for the other branches.

```
commit='deadbeef'
for branch in $(git branch | sed -n '/master/!s#^[ *\t]##p'); do
   echo "cherry-picking onto $branch"
   git checkout "$branch" && git cherry-pick "$commit"
done
```

As an aside, note the preference for lowercase shell variables, the quoting, not using the `g` flag in `sed` when you only expect a single match on each line, and avoiding the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

The use of `\t` in the sed script isn't entirely portable; maybe try `[*[:space:]]` instead of `[ *\t]`.

Cherry-picking an individual commit is of course also much more specific than merging all of `master` into each branch, which could well be a complete no-no for others who struggle with this.

Comment: Agreed. The script is a prototype and should be cleaned up before being used long-term.

Comment: The comment is a good reminder about `grep` (piping cats is a terrible habit I still catching my self at) and the mention of `sed` portability adds value to the discussion as well. I see no reason for a downvote.